# Value in one sheet and returning value to right

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I've been tasked with creating a macro that will act like a VLOOKUP, but on a wider scale. Basically, we want the macro to look at the value at the top of a column, then search for that value in a different sheets column. If it finds that value, it should return the value in the cell to the immediate right of it. Once done, it should remove any duplicate values and blank cells in that column.

I then need the code to loop to the next column and repeat until there is no more values left to look up.

I can get the first column of data perfectly, but I can't seem to make it work on subsequent columns (loops or direct references). Can anyone point me in the right direction? (Note, I've disabled final row to test the loop on 10 rows only due to the large amount of data in each row).

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReturnActions()

    Dim itemNumber As String
    Dim finalRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws1 As Object
    Dim ws2 As Object

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Intermediate_Data")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Final Workings")

    ws2.Activate

    Range("A2").Select

    itemNumber = ws1.Range("A1").value
    finalRow = ws2.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlUp)).Select

    ws2.Activate

    'For i = 2 To finalRow
    For i = 2 To ws2.Range("A10").Row
        If Cells(i, 1) = itemNumber Then
            ws2.Cells(i, 2).Copy
            ws1.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial    'Transpose:=True
        End If

    Next i

    'Remove duplicates and blanks from data
    With ws1.Range("A:A")
        .value = .value
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Range("A2").Offset(0, 1).Select

    'Select data worksheet
    ws1.Activate

    'Select cell A1
    Range("A1").Select

    'Select next column item number
    itemNumber = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    'Execute code
    ws2.Activate

    'For i = 2 To finalRow
    For i = 2 To ws2.Range("B10").Row
        If Cells(i, 2) = itemNumber Then
            ws2.Cells(i, 3).Copy
            ws1.Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial    'Transpose:=True
        End If

    Next i

    With ws1.Range("B:B")
        .value = .value
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: James, I'd like to help you work through this, but I'm having trouble finding where in your code you attempt to work with data in a subsequent column. Can you give me some guidance?

Comment: Hi Jim, I have tried to start the next column by the line: Range("A2").Offset(0, 1).Select. This is where I have tried to start referring to the next column to look in once the tidying up of the data has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code'

- Removed unnecessary cell selections
- Toggle Application.ScreenUpdating to improve speed
- Used Intersect to trim the column reference to fit the data
- Fixed a couple of bad variable assignments

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub ReturnActions()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim itemNumber As String
        Dim finalRow As Long
        Dim i As Long
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet

        Set ws1 = Worksheets("Intermediate_Data")
        Set ws2 = Worksheets("Final Workings")
        Range("").Value = 2
        itemNumber = ws1.Range("A1").Value

        With ws2

            finalRow = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Row

            For i = 2 To finalRow
                If .Cells(i, 1) = itemNumber Then
                    .Cells(i, 2).Copy
                    ws1.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial    'Transpose:=True
                End If

            Next i

        End With

        'Remove duplicates and blanks from data
        With Intersect(ws1.Range("A:A"), ws1.UsedRange)
            .Value = .Value
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
            On Error Resume Next
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        'Select next column item number
        itemNumber = ws1.Range("B1").Value

        'For i = 2 To finalRow
        For i = 2 To ws2.Range("B10").Row
            If Cells(i, 2) = itemNumber Then
                ws2.Cells(i, 3).Copy
                ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial    'Transpose:=True
            End If

        Next i

        With Intersect(ws1.Range("B:B"), ws1.UsedRange)
            .Value = .Value
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
            On Error Resume Next
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to work out where I was going wrong. I had not defined the itemNumber when starting the second loop (variable of .Select, not .Value).

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already accepted an answer but I'll post this anyway, as there may be a simpler way of achieving your task and it may be useful to you in the future.

Just from a sequencing point of view, is there are reason why you wouldn't remove your blank cells all in one go at the start of your project?

From a programming perspective, I feel you may be relying on the automation of key-strokes (ie maro recording) more than you need to. If you read the look-up data source into an array, then you could produce more of a 'pure' VBA solution which would vastly simplify your code.

I'm not sure I precisely understand what you are trying to achieve, but the code below provides an example of how I have interpreted your task. I don't think it would take much to adjust to suit your own needs:

```
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet, finalSheet As Worksheet
Dim dataColumn As Range, newCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim columnValues As Variant, searchValue As Variant
Dim r As Long, c As Long

Set finalSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final Workings")
Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Intermediate_Data")

'Remove all the blanks
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = dataSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Delete xlShiftUp

'Read the final workings
columnValues = finalSheet.UsedRange.Value2

'Loop through the columns to find values
c = 1 'this is the column index of your lookup values
For Each dataColumn In dataSheet.UsedRange.Columns
    searchValue = dataColumn.Cells(1).Value2
    For r = 2 To UBound(columnValues, 1) 'start with 2 because 1 is a header
        If columnValues(r, c) = searchValue Then
            'Write value into new cell at bottom of column
            Set newCell = dataColumn.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
            newCell.Value = columnValues(r, c + 1)
            'Delete duplicates
            dataSheet.Range(dataColumn.Cells(2), newCell).RemoveDuplicates Header:=xlNo
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    c = c + 1
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```